# Call multiple webservice and parse xml

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xml-parsing

i am stuck in my app in which i need to call two webservice in same viewcontroller ,and parse the xml.
But i have no idea how can i parse the data of both the webservice.

Comment: Post code please. This problem is way too general as it is.

Comment: +1 For you , Good Question !!!...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can achieve this by creating two different connection object for
   two web service  method calls.Then in connection delegate methods by
   comparing the connection objects do the  appropriate task.Also to
   parse the xml response call the methods in
   connectionDidFinishLoading method by comparing the connection
   object.
2. Other way is after calling the request,in
   connectionDidFinishLoading method convert the received response to 
   NSString & find any string which differentiate the two responses to
   call the respective parsing method

Answer (score 2):

Search before asking there is so many questions of this kind already asked .Here is the link [call multiple webservices on same view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433517/multiple-web-service-calls-on-same-viewcontroller-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

The question is very general.

In a similar case I encountered where I had to work against 2 web-services You can either save the requests (to compare to the delegate callback and know which request is which) or you can use something like AFNetworking:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Which can give you the responses in a block method.
If you need all the data at once - You should call upon a function that checks that both requests and data parsing have happened.

To parse the XML itself you can either go for an AFNetworking extension like:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFKissXMLRequestOperation

Or you can go for a simpler solution (That would work with any networking framework) like:
https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary

(Assuming you do not want to use the built in iOS6 methods).

Answer (score 1):

Its simple 
I think you may have two different Url to send the request right
and you have only one method to get that response right
so I faced this problem but its simple 
please maintain the flag

```
if(flag)
{
   then your first response
}
else
{
   your second response
}
```