# Multiple web service calls at the same time in iOS

Tags: ios, json, web-services, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

In my app i need to call two services at a time. for single service i am using the below code:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
// Instantiate a session object.
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"my link"];

// Create a data task object to perform the data downloading.
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if (error != nil) {
        // If any error occurs then just display its description on the console.
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        // If no error occurs, check the HTTP status code.
        NSInteger HTTPStatusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

        // If it's other than 200, then show it on the console.
        if (HTTPStatusCode != 200) {
            NSLog(@"HTTP status code = %d", (int)HTTPStatusCode);
        } else {
            NSMutableArray *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];


            NSLog(@"json data ==========> %@", jsonData);


        }


    }
}];

// Resume the task.
[task resume];
```

by using this i am getting the data. Now, at the same time i need to call another service. How can i achieve this? and How i will get the data?

Comment: Why dont you create a class and define a function which will take URL as a parameter and start the service and returns the response to you when its done using delegates

Comment: Try with below `URL` help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433517/multiple-web-service-calls-on-same-viewcontroller-iphone

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman thanks for your suggestion. I created a class same like that. It is working fine.